# slim php the requested url not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I am fairly new to slim php, i have a little problem but i can't seem to find it, The error is coming from xampp which is weird. if i navigate to localhost/db_api/hello it works, but when i add args it just doesn't work.

[image: Problem i get]

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "4.*",
        "slim/psr7": "^1.6",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.8",
        "nyholm/psr7-server": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^2",
        "laminas/laminas-diactoros": "^3.1"
    }
}
```

.htaccess in public:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

.htaccess in src:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess in the root of db_api:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ src/ [L]
    RewriteRule (^[^/]*$) src/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

index.php

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->setBasePath('/db_api');

$app->get('/hello', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You only need 2 `.htaccess` files.

1. Delete the current `.htaccess` in the project root directory
2. Move the file `src/.htaccess` to the project root directory
3. Move your index.php file to `public/index.php`

Comment: it didn't work , the problem only occurs when i try to add an arg followed by a / example  '/factories{id}/sections' doesn't work but '/factories{id}' works, 'factories/{id} doesn't work, it's weird everything else works fine

Comment: I suspect the reason is that the `/hello` route is defined twice. This will not work. Try to remove the first route for `/hello`.